# Fixed elements in a fixed navbar

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a navbar that has a fixed position and has elements inside of it that are also fixed:

[image]

```
.navbar { 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.content-area {
 overflow: scroll;
}

.top-area {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

I have two areas that should be fixed to the top and the bottom and a content area in the middle that's overflow scrolls under the bottom area. When I add `position: fixed;` to .top-area or .bottom-area they disappear to the top. Why can't I fix an element onto the navbar?

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="top-area">
  </div>
  <div class="content-area">
  <p> Content here </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-area">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Elements are taken out of the normal flow of html page. Try to set the z-index value to these classes. Give higher e.g. `z-index: 100` to those which you want to be on the top. 
If you could show your html, I could fix it more precisely for you :).

Comment: Hmm, no luck with z-index. I added the html if that helps.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. you want to fix the nav bar to the top and the navbar as your html shows contains "top-area", "content-area" and "bottom-area". Try to set the fix position on nav-bar only and it will still keep all the elements inside it to the top.

Comment: Navbar is fixed but I'd like top-area to stick to the top and bottom-area to stick to the bottom and content-area to scroll. Right now top and bottom areas scroll down with content-area.

Comment: then try to add give margins to them as they will overlap each other. Look here  `       .navbar {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .content-area {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        .top-area {
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }`

Comment: Got it. The (simple) problem was I wasn't specifying a width. Thanks for the help :)